# applications of vectors: woman in canoe

Tags: vectors

A woman in canoe paddles due west at 4mi/hour relative to the water in current that flows northwest at 2 mi/hour. Find the speed and direction of the canoe relative to the shore.

I drew a diagram but afterwards I'm stuck with what to do. [image]

Answer (score 0):

So you have two velocity vectors separated by an angle $135^{\circ}$. Your drawing looks to be good: what you want do is add the two vectors. To add the vectors, calculate the magnitude of the hypotenuse of that triangle. The **Law of Cosines** states
$$ a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A$$
$$ b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac\cos B$$
$$ c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C.$$
[image]

In our case, we know $c$, $A$, and $b$ and would like to find $a$. Use
$$a^2= b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A.$$
Here $c=4, b=2, A=135^{\circ}.$
You can finish the computation, I'm sure.

**NOTE: The credit for the picture goes to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html.**

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula for resultant vecto $r=\sqrt{p^2+q^2+2pqcos(\theta)}$